# How to use same Microsoft Account between Windows Store App and Companion Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps, asp.net-identity

I have a MVC5 website and WebApi using ASP.Net identity. I have configured the website to use Microsoft Account as an external login.

The Windows Store App will use the WebApi, and the user should have the same identity when using their Microsoft Account from either the website or the app. As users are already logged into their Microsoft Account when using Windows Store App, I don't want them to have to enter their credentials again.

I'm wondering what is a good way for my app to be able to access the WebApi. Can I retrieve the Microsoft Account authentication token and pass that to my website's token endpoint with an authorization code grant in order to retrieve the token for my app to use to access the WebApi? Is there another way?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes - I like this question and would like to find an answer as well.

Comment: Assuming that you are using bearer tokens in the WebAPI, you could use refresh tokens, and have the Windows Store App re-authenticate once on first run, and then store the refresh token.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Do you mean get and store a refresh token from LiveConnect or from my website's token endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I want to avoid making changes to my WebApi's Account Controller as this process does not really fit into the MVC part of the website as it does not need to redirect to views, etc.  So I plan to extend the Token endpoint with a custom grant type (e.g. exchange), which will return the local token to the consumer.  Consumers will send the Token endpoint a request with a grant_type of exchange, my app's client id and secret, the name of the external provider (e.g. MicrosoftAccount), and the access code from the external provider.  For example, the app will send a request like this:

http://myhost.com/token?grant_type=exchange&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=SECRET&provider=MicrosoftAccount&code=LIVESDKACCESSCODE

I'll provide an implementation of the ApplicationOAuthProvider's GrantCustomExtension method, the pseudo code will be like this

- validate the client id and secret
- If client id and secret are valid, use the access code to get an access token from the Live SDK
- parse the Live SDK access token to retrieve the id value
- try to find the corresponding id value in the AspNetUserLogins table
- If the login is not found, add a new AspNetUser record for the user and a record in the AspNetUserLogins table
- create a token for the user and return the token

Once the app has the token, it can be stored in the Credential Locker for any other calls to the WebApi